# I need a way of hardcoding password to a cmd (or bat) file at the time of running rather than typing it every time

Tags: file, batch-file

I need a way of hardcoding password to a cmd (or bat) file at the time of running rather than typing it every time.

```
@echo off
title Embed Secret
cd C:\steghide\
for /R C:\steghide\train\ %%f in (*.jpg) do steghide embed -cf "%%f" -ef "message.txt"
pause
```

The executable steghide asks for a pass phrase everytime it is called. How do I hardcode it inside my code.

Comment: try this `for /R C:\steghide\train\ %%f in (*.jpg) do echo p@ssword| steghide embed -cf "%%f" -ef "message.txt"`

Comment: I see you did not bother to read the [manual](http://steghide.sourceforge.net/documentation/manpage.php) for the application.  The passphrase can be provided as an option to the program when you execute it. `-p "a very long passphrase"`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's working now.